# In swift, Is there a possibility to add a collection view within a collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am having a collection view and its collection view cell. Is there any possibility to add a collection view within that collection view cell? Can anyone please help with this.

Comment: yes, it is possible. but, describe what you're trying to allow the user to do and we can tell you if there's a better way...

Comment: Iam having a collection view for displaying the images of gallery. If in gallery having the folder, in that folder we have multiple images, i have to animate that images with in single collection view cell of a collection view cell.

Comment: Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, though i might be tempted to use a table view where each cell has a collection view in it.

I'd also look at creating a view controller to manage each cells content and making those controllers children of the main VC.

Be careful how you reuse cells and how many child VCs you keep alive or you might use too much memory.